# Apache .htacess - 301 redirect doesn't work at all. Using dynamic and friendly URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to create a 301 redirect from a page in my **homepage** subfolder to **another page in the same subfolder**. Example:

> (1) samedomain.com/homepage/discussions/62-info ***to***
> (2) samedomain.com/homepage/newinfopost

However, it's not working at all, and I have tried a lot of RewriteRule codes already.

**Some relevant information:**

- Both pages are pulled from the database by my software, which is installed in the homepage subfolder
- Both pages are friendly URLs. My software installed another .htaccess file in homepage to get that done
- RewriteEngine is on

**What I have tried:**

- I have tried disabling friendly URLs temporarily and removing the .htaccess from the subfolder, leaving only the main .htaccess active
- The .htaccess file (from the main folder) is working. I tested it with different rules and it's fine
- Some RewriteRules I have tried:

> RewriteRule homepage/discussions/62-info/(.*)
> https://samedomain.com/homepage/newinfopost/$1 [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteRule homepage/discussions/62-info/(.*) /homepage/newinfopost/$1
> [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteRule /homepage/discussions/62-info/$ /homepage/newinfopost/$1
> [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteRule ^/?homepage/discussions/62-info/(.*)$
> https://samedomain.com/homepage/newinfopost/$1 [L,R=301]

The .htaccess in the subfolder (that is managed by my software to transform URLs into friendly ones) is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /homepage/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map|webp)(\?|$) /homepage/404error.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /homepage/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But like I said, I have tried removing that file and disabling friendly URLs too.

**Edit:**

I believe my pages are dynamic. When they're not friendly URLs, they look like this:

> https://samedomain.com/homepage/index.php?app=discussions&id=62

**Test 1 based on @MrWhite's answer:**

```
RewriteRule ^discussions/62-info$ /homepage/newinfopost [R=302,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /homepage/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map|webp)(\?|$) /homepage/404error.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /homepage/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `/homepage/discussions/62-info` to `/homepage/newinfopost` then you should add the following to the very top of the `/homepage/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^discussions/62-info$ /homepage/newinfopost [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument) matches a URL-path relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. So, this should not contain `homepage/` when in the `/homepage/.htaccess` file.

Note that in `.htaccess` the URL-path that is matched does not start with a slash.

When the `/homepage/.htaccess` file is present (contain mod_rewrite directives) then any mod_rewrite directives in the parent config (ie. in `/.htaccess`) are completely overridden - they are not even processed (by default).

Always test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. You should clear your browser cache before testing.

---

```
RewriteRule homepage/discussions/62-info/(.*) https://samedomain.com/homepage/newinfopost/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule homepage/discussions/62-info/(.*) /homepage/newinfopost/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule /homepage/discussions/62-info/$ /homepage/newinfopost/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?homepage/discussions/62-info/(.*)$ https://samedomain.com/homepage/newinfopost/$1 [L,R=301]
```

None of these would match the example URL, since the example does not include a trailing slash. The 3rd rule also has an erroneous slash prefix. (But why do you have a capturing subpattern and `$1` backreference? There doesn't appear to be anything that needs "capturing" in your example URL?)

It would also depend on where (and which file) these directives are being used.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteBase /home/
> ```

In the directives you've posted the `RewriteBase` directive is not being used. However, it would seem to be set incorrectly, as the base URL would seem to be `/homepage`, not `/home`.

Comment: Very good info, @MrWhite! So, if I understood it well, I would need to add your RewriteRule to the very top of my homepage .htacess file - before the IfModule part along with another "RewriteEngine on", right?

Comment: About the RewriteBase part, I probably mixed it up somehow, but what I currently have is really "/homepage". Thanks for pointing it out though, I'll edit the main post.

Comment: @Hilas Yes, but you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive. The only concern is that you say this file is "managed by your software"... you obviously need to ensure that it won't end up overwriting your custom rule!?

Comment: I edited the main post to include your code. Did I write it correctly? If so, it's still not working :(

Comment: Hm, good point there. Is there a way to easily debug that, to check if the software is overwriting the custom rule? However, I tested something like ``RewriteRule ^$ /homepage/ [L,R=302]`` and it works fine. The problematic part seems to be the condition (the first part of the RewriteRule) when it's about a dynamic page in "homepage".

Comment: @Hilas Yes, you wrote it correctly. And this is in the `/homepage/.htaccess` file? And you are requesting the URL `/homepage/discussions/62-info` exactly? "to check if the software is overwriting the custom rule?" - open the file and see that the rule is still there. (?) "I tested something like `RewriteRule ^$ /homepage/ [L,R=302]`" and it works fine" - that rule should not "work fine" if it's in the `/homepage/.htaccess` file - it would create an endless redirect loop. (That rule would only "work" if it's in the root `.htaccess` file, but then it should be overridden by the subdir file.)

Comment: Yes, it's in the ``/homepage/.htaccess`` file. And yes, I'm requesting exactly that URL. I even removed the trailing slash to make sure. About the rule working fine, my mistake again. I tested that in the main .htaccess file, not in the subfolder.

Comment: @Hilas Try the following instead: `RewriteRule foo /homepage/newinfopost [R=302,L]` and request `/homepage/foo`.

Comment: That one works! It must be software-related then, right? I'll check something here and report back.

Comment: @Hilas Put some anchors on the regex. ie. try it like this instead... `RewriteRule ^bar$ /homepage/newinfopost [R=302,L]` and request `/homepage/bar` - does it still work?

Comment: okaaayy, so your comments brought something to mind and I did a little digging. I looked into the database and I saw that ``/homepage/discussions/62-info`` still existed in the database. I believe it wasn't deleted, it was just hidden. So I guess the htaccess rule was really being overwritten by the software (I thought it should be the other way around?). Anyway, I deleted that and it's finally solved!! I just had to change your ``/homepage/newinfopost`` to ``newinfopost``, since they're all in the same subfolder. Thank you so much for your help, MrWhite!!!! You are amazing :)

Comment: MrWhite, just one quick question. How do I make the redirect work with or without the trailing slash? Right it only works without it.

Comment: Adding /?$ at the end seems to have solved it :)

Comment: @Hilas You should not have to remove the old URL from the database. `.htaccess` is processed before your application/database is even started. The only issue that might occur is if something happened _after_ the initial redirect?! Check the network traffic. "I just had to change your /homepage/newinfopost to newinfopost" - by changing the _substitution_ in that way the rule is now dependent on `RewriteBase` (defined later in the file). To make the trailing slash optional change `$` to `/?$` at the end of the regex.

Comment: Hm, I agree, which is why it's weird. I have no idea why or how the software was overruling the custom rule, but indeed it was. Removing it from the software's database was the ultimate solution. I'll try to look into it further when I have some extra time. "by changing the substitution in that way the rule is now dependent on RewriteBase (defined later in the file)" I tried keeping /homepage/ in the substitution, but then I was being redirected to /homepage/homepage/ (twice). I guess because the .htaccess I'm editing is already in the homepage folder? Anyway, it looks good now, thanks to you!

Comment: @Hilas "I tried keeping /homepage/ in the substitution, but then I was being redirected to /homepage/homepage/ (twice)" - That would only happen if the slash prefix was omitted from the _substitution_ string, ie. `homepage/newinfopost`, as opposed to `/homepage/newinfopost`. (?) It would seem to be working OK for the other rules where you have included the `/homepage/` prefix?